# Errors aren't thrown neither inside RactiveJS observers nor listeners

Tags: ractivejs

I've noticed that listening / observing functions attached to ractive instance:

```
ractive.on('event', someListener);
ractive.observe('keypath.to.data.property', someListener);
```

don't throw errors (when they should). Am I doing something wrong, or is it just a downside of using eval-alike `Function` constructor in Ractive core?

Errors debugging is so hard in such a case...

**EDIT**: The problem I've written about occurs only when observer is registered inside an **`oncomplete`** function.

```
 var ractive = new Ractive({
    el: '#container',
    template: 'a: <input value="{{a}}"><br>b: <input value="{{b}}">',
    data: {
        a: 'alpha',
        b: 'beta'
    }, 
    oncomplete: function(){
        this.observe('a', function(val){
            alert('@oncomplete ' + val + missingVar_oncomplete);
        }, { init: false });       
    }
});
```

Test cases: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqgoacvz/

Comment: Looks like an issue in Ractive. Investigating...

Answer (score 0):

[Issue](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1425) and [PR](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/pull/1426) have been made to address `oncomplete` errors not showing up on console.

As the issue stems from `oncomplete` being called asynchronously, you could also move your observers and event handlers to an earlier lifecycle event. They can come as early as `oninit`, or in `onrender` if there's DOM access. Obviously if there's post DOM transition reasons, they would need to stay in `oncomplete`.